# Simplifying a logical formula

Tags: logic, disjunctive-normal-form

I am trying to follow through the teacher's notes on transforming a formula to disjunctive normal form, but an example problem got me stuck.
So the starting formula is this:

```
     (X ⊃ Y ) ∨ ¬(¬Y ⊃ X ∨ ¬Z)
```

In the teacher's notation, ∧ is conjuntcion, ⊃ is implication, v is disjunction and ¬ is negation.
As a first step, I use De Morgan's law, to remove the implications, which results in:

```
     (¬X ∨ Y ) ∨ (¬Y ∧ ¬(X ∨ ¬Z))
```

Then I deal with the negations, so that they only apply to atomic formulas:

```
     (¬X ∨ Y ) ∨ (¬Y ∧ ¬X ∧ Z)
```

I Write out the conjunction of disjunctions like this:

```
     (¬X ∨ Y ∨ ¬Y ) ∧ (¬X ∨ Y ∨ ¬X) ∧ (¬X ∨ Y ∨ Z)
```

And then simplify by removing the first bracketed expression, which yields a tautolgy and removing the ¬X from the second one, as ¬X v ¬X = ¬X:

```
     (¬X ∨ Y ) ∧ (¬X ∨ Y ∨ Z)
```

And, here comes the part, which got me stuck. In the teacher's lecture notes, after the very same construction process, the final, simplified result is

```
     ¬X ∨ Y
```

And I just can not wrap my head around how this simplification is made. It makes intuitive sense, that a disjunction of two tautologically equivalent formulas could be reduced to one of the formulas, but in this case I have written out the truth tables of (¬X ∨ Y) and (¬X ∨ Y ∨ Z) and they are not equivalent. Can somebody explain how this simplification comes to be? I just can not seem to figure it out myself... Also if somebody could provide some useful resource on the process of simplifying such formulas would be a great help, since our teacher's notes are very skimpy in explanations, and I could not find step-by-step examples on the internet yet.  Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What you wrote out here: `(¬X ∨ Y ∨ ¬Y ) ∧ (¬X ∨ Y ∨ ¬X) ∧ (¬X ∨ Y ∨ Z)` is the conjunctions of disjunctions, not the other way around.

Comment: Indeed that was written the wrong way I corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as the absorption law:
$$p\wedge(p\vee q) \equiv p$$

$$p\wedge(p\vee q)\equiv (p\vee F) \wedge (p\vee q) \equiv p\vee (F\wedge q) \equiv p\vee F\equiv p$$

It is also easily verified using the truth table.

Now think of $p$ as $\neg X\vee Y$ and $q$ as $Z$.

Comment: Oh this explains it! The same is described in our notes as "elimination", but I failed to draw an analogy between that and my problem. But yeah, it totally makes sense now. A huge thanks to you!